# Problema Base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Buenas! Necesito que me ayuden a saber como subir correctamente o qué hacer con este problema de mi base de datos:
Subí mi página web a el host de 000webhost.com y todo va bien de echo les dejo el link de mi página: [Mi página web](https://copasable.000webhostapp.com/)
El problema es al darle a Iniciar sesión todo funciona perfecto en mi pc pero no agarra la base, se queda validando... y no entiendo bien que puede ser, bueno si sé, es algo de los permisos o por lo menos eso dice:
[image: Error al abrir el archivo conexion.php en el webhost]
Qué debo de hacer para solucionar ese problema?

Comment: Solicita a los del hosting te den los datos para conexión a la Base de Datos (usuario, contraseña, puerto... etc.), se me hace raro que te den acceso a un **root** para conectarte a la BD; más en caso de ser host compartido, quizas si fuera dedicado.

Comment: Ya pude bro gracias, solo era subir mi archivo con los datos de la base del host aun que no me funcionará en local en mi pc subiéndolo sí, eso era todo-

Answer (score 3):

Dice `Access denied for user 'root'@'2a02:4780:bad:f00d::2' (using password: NO)`. Eso quiere decir que intenta conectarse a la base de datos con el usuario `root` sin especificar la contraseña.

Verifica si configuraste las credenciales correctamente.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta bro,ya lo pude hacer funcionar.